# Почему не ставится запятая перед "НО"?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

"Термопаста под крышкой — главное «НО» на пути к успеху в этом деле".

В роли какого члена предложения выступает "НО"?

Answer (score 1):

Замените ваше НО на любое существительное, и сразу все станет ясно. *Термопаста – главное препятствие*. Сказуемое, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

В толковом словаре (В. Лопатин, Л. Лопатина):
[**НО**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=DSeFAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB.,%20%D1%81%D1%80.%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%20(%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3.).%20%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%BE.&source=bl&ots=CxHp6ZwjU9&sig=ACfU3U1TAP5rOQFDPLSOMhqwCB40DmwwZg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj__uGoyIziAhVHpYsKHWkwCUIQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB.%2C%20%D1%81%D1%80.%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%20(%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3.).%20%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%BE.&f=false)
**2.** *в знач. **сущ.**, нескл., ср.* Возражение, препятствие (разг.). *Есть маленькое но.*

[**Вопрос № 278745**](https://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)
Как все-таки правильно — с кавычками или без: есть только одно "но" (но)?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Словарная фиксация — без кавычек.
**Но**, *неизм.; ср.* Обстоятельство, мешающее чему-либо, препятствие; возражение.
*Никаких но — выполняйте задание. Давайте без всяких но. Без но не получится. В этом деле очень много но.*

**Термопаста под крышкой — главное но на пути к успеху в этом деле.**

**Но** здесь выступает в роли существительного (не союза!), поэтому перед ним запятая не нужна.
В предложении является сказуемым (между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным существительным в именительном падеже, стоит тире).
Кавычки не требуются.